# create a Droppable Component that is aware of drop events

Tags: react-native, drag-and-drop

Implementing drag and drop, I wonder if it is possible to create a Drop-Component, that knows itself, when something was dropped onto it.
Because currently have to do math to calculate, where the component was dropped. When I refactor the gui, I will have to recalibrate the formulas.